# visual studio 2017, d3dx9.h No such file or directory

Tags: visual-studio-2017, header-files

I'm trying to compile mpc-hc. Compilation instructions say to use VS2015, but I went for VS2017 instead.

What package should I install to get Direct3D9 headers?

Comment: It was an ancient DirectX SDK header file, it was retired 7 years ago.  The project wiki tells you where to obtain that old SDK version in the "Compiling MPC-HC" article.  Be sure to read all of it.

Comment: @HansPassant Thank you. Thought I missed an option in visual studio, since they now allow to choose what to install.